# MongoDB: Last slot 00:00:00 is not returned in date range query

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB document with date ranges from 00:00 - 00:00 for a day having one hour slots. I need to query these date ranges from 20:00:00-23:59:59 to get last 4 slots but the last slot 23:00:00-00:00:00 is not returned in the response.

**Document:**

```
{
  "_id": "18d2ec8f-ae77-4024-9872-46ff2ef828f2",
  "slots": [
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T01:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T02:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T03:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T07:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T09:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T10:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T11:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T13:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T14:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T15:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T15:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T16:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T17:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T18:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T18:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T19:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T19:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T20:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T20:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T21:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T21:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T22:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T22:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "start_time": "1900-01-01T23:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the below query using Python

```
{'slots.start_time': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 59)}, 'slots.end_time': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 0)}}
```

I need to get the last slot too from the document, can anyone please help me with the query?

Comment: Use operator `$lte`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this via the aggregation framework is best for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
  "slots.start_time": {
    $lt: "1900-01-01T23:59:00.000Z"
  },
  "slots.end_time": {
    $gte: "1900-01-01T20:00:00.000Z"
  }
 }
},
{
 $addFields: {
  slots: {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$slots",
      "as": "s",
      "cond": {
        $and: [
          {
            "$lt": [
              "$$s.start_time",
              "1900-01-01T23:59:00.000Z"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$gte": [
              "$$s.end_time",
              "1900-01-01T20:00:00.000Z"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Match the values that you need.
2. Since your values are nested in array "slots" , you will need to use $filter to filter only the elements covering the conditions.

For best results index on slots.start_time & slots.end_time is good to have...

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SzJSZPG7WTf)